# PHP $_GET request not working

Tags: php, url

I'm new to PHP and the answer might be easy but even after several search I didn't manage to fix that simple issue.

So I'm trying to get params from the URL using $_GET, here is a sample code:

```
<?php

$ee = $_GET["search"];
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "ee : [" . $ee . "]");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

The url I use is the following: `http://localhost:63342/friend-s-app/sources/home.html?search=test`

The JSON file contains: `ee : []`

From what I understood it should be : `ee: [test]`

Here's the code from where i'm calling it (AngularJS)

```
$http.post("../datas/getprojects.php").
        success(function() {
            $http.get("../datas/results.json")
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.tiles = response.records;
                });
        });
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Post the HTML form that calls your script. By the way, we cannnot access your localhost.

Comment: Anytime you access that page with no `search` param it will write the file with the empty ee.

Comment: have you tried echo-ing out $ee to confirm it's capturing the correct information?

Comment: Yeah I know it but the url I use is http://localhost:63342/friend-s-app/sources/home.html?search=test so there's actually a param (search=test) and echoing gives the same result, ee doesn't contain anything

Comment: Ok - that's helpful. I added an answer below that should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP code you've provided needs to live in the file you're accessing with the URL. Since that's the case, it needs to be "home.php", not "home.html".